# Copy specific filenames from different files

Tags: powershell

So I've got a bunch of folders with a file in each of them called: CLOSEUP-PLAIN.PNG and need to copy each of them to a new folder.
The folder layout is:

- Listing Images

  - 000001

    - CLOSEUP-PLAIN.PNG
  - 000002

    - CLOSEUP-PLAIN.PNG
  - 000003

    - CLOSEUP-PLAIN.PNG
  - 000004

    - CLOSEUP-PLAIN.PNG

And i need to copy all of them CLOSEUP-PLAIN files into a new folder, Preferable if possible to rename it to the folder it was in.
Thank you for any help provided!

Comment: What have you tried? You could use get-childitem -recurse *.png and work around the results with string operations like indexof etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below, replacing the path to the source and the destination directories:

```
[string] $Source = "D:\Listing Images"
[string] $Destination = "D:\Output"

if (!(Test-Path $Destination)) {
    New-Item -Type Directory $Destination
}

Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq 'CLOSEUP-PLAIN.PNG'} | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item  $_.FullName "$Destination\$($_.Directory.Name).png" }
```

This finds all of the images named "CLOSEUP-PLAIN.PNG" in any of the folders beneath $Source and copies them to $Destination, with their name set to the folder they were found in.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this, but unfortunately i get this error: https://gyazo.com/5d3355a544a1f36982df6be83d261af8

Comment: The -File flag was only added in PowerShell 3.0 (I guess you are on 2.0) I've updated the code so that should work in all PowerShell versions.